# How to select data from mysql for display like this?

Tags: php, mysql

How to select data from mysql for display like this ?

i have 3 table

1 table: h_test

```
 ____________________
|  id  |    pro_id   |
|  1   |    111111   |
|  2   |    222222   |
|  3   |    333333   |
|  4   |    444444   |
|__5___|____555555___|
```

2 table: c_test

```
 __________________________________
|  id  |    pro_id   |   country   |
|  1   |    111111   |     usa     |
|  2   |    111111   |     uk      |
|  3   |    222222   |     usa     |
|  4   |    222222   |    china    |
|  5   |    333333   |     usa     |
|  6   |    333333   |     uk      |
|  7   |    444444   |    japan    |
|  8   |    444444   |     usa     |
|  9   |    555555   |     uk      |
|__10__|____555555___|_____japan___|
```

3 table: i_test

```
 __________________________________
|  id  |    pro_id   |   number    |
|  1   |    111111   |     10      |
|  2   |    111111   |     20      |
|  3   |    222222   |     1       |
|  4   |    222222   |     5       |
|  5   |    333333   |     10      |
|  6   |    333333   |     20      |
|  7   |    444444   |     20      |
|  8   |    444444   |     50      |
|  9   |    555555   |     1       |
|__10__|____555555___|_____5_______|
```

Then i run this code

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM h_test INNER JOIN c_test ON c_test.pro_id = h_test.pro_id
                             INNER JOIN i_test ON i_test.pro_id = h_test.pro_id
        WHERE h_test.pro_id != '0' AND c_test.country = 'usa' AND i_test.number > '5' GROUP BY h_test.pro_id order by i_test.number desc ";
```

And after test code , i get this data

```
 _______________________________________________
|  id  |    pro_id   |   country   |   number  |
|  7   |    444444   |     usa     |     20    |
|  1   |    111111   |     usa     |     10    |
|__5___|____333333___|_____usa_____|_____10____|
```

But i want to get data like this , How to select

```
 _______________________________________________
|  id  |    pro_id   |   country   |   number  |
|  7   |    444444   |     usa     |     50    |
|  1   |    111111   |     usa     |     20    |
|__5___|____333333___|_____usa_____|_____20____|
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: Instead of "AND i_test.number > '5'" try with "AND i_test.number = (SUBQUERY SELECTING MAX(NUMBER) FROM i_test )" ... (it's just a hint, obviously you need to create the exact subquery the extract the correct number).

Comment: @Masiorama - not work thank..

Comment: Did you try creating the actual sub query, or you did just copy and paste my suggestion?

Comment: yes, copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$SQL = "SELECT c.id, c.pro_id, b.country, max(c.number) FROM h_test a 
        INNER JOIN c_test b ON a.pro_id = b.pro_id
        INNER JOIN i_test c ON a.pro_id = c.pro_id
        WHERE a.pro_id != '0' AND b.country = 'usa' AND c.number > '5' GROUP BY a.pro_id order by c.number desc";
```

or

```
$SQL = "SELECT i_test.id, i_test.pro_id, c_test.country, max(i_test.number) FROM h_test INNER JOIN c_test ON c_test.pro_id = h_test.pro_id INNER JOIN i_test ON i_test.pro_id = h_test.pro_id
        WHERE h_test.pro_id != '0' AND c_test.country = 'usa' AND i_test.number > '5' GROUP BY h_test.pro_id order by i_test.number desc ";
```

Comment: error



`Error Query [SELECT c.id, c.pro_id, c.country, max(c.number) FROM h_test a INNER JOIN c_test b ON c_test.pro_id = h_test.pro_id INNER JOIN i_test c ON i_test.pro_id = h_test.pro_id WHERE a.pro_id != '0' AND b.country = 'usa' AND c.number > '5' GROUP BY a.pro_id order by c.number desc ]`

Comment: it is called alias. I remove the alias and its should works now. Try the code in below now @robertwersaq

Comment: using asterisk (*) in coding is not recommended unless you just trying the result. Mark as answer if this is answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to little tweak in your query

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM h_test INNER JOIN c_test ON c_test.pro_id = h_test.pro_id
                             INNER JOIN i_test ON i_test.pro_id = h_test.pro_id
        WHERE h_test.pro_id != '0' AND c_test.country = 'usa' AND i_test.number > '5' **AND i_test.pro_id in (SELECT max(pro_id) FROM  i_test GROUP BY number )**";

Comment: could you please give me the output?

Comment: SELECT h_test.id,h_test.pro_id,c_test.country ,max(number) FROM h_test INNER JOIN c_test ON c_test.pro_id = h_test.pro_id INNER JOIN i_test ON i_test.pro_id = h_test.pro_id WHERE h_test.pro_id != '0' AND c_test.country = 'usa' AND number>5 GROUP BY h_test.pro_id ORDER BY h_test.pro_id DESC